# Mongo SSL with Java Exception sending message

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, keystore

I'm using mongo to create SSL connection between the java client and a mongo replica set. It worked fine with mongo shell so I assume I have done something wrong with java. There is already a thread that is similar to this but it didn't help.
Here is my configuration:

Starting two mongod:

```
mongod --keyFile D:\mongoDBFiles\mongokey --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile D:\mongoDBFiles\mongodb.pem --port 27017 --dbpath D:\mongoDBFiles\node1 --replSet foo --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
mongod --keyFile D:\mongoDBFiles\mongokey --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile D:\mongoDBFiles\mongodb.pem --port 27018 --dbpath D:\mongoDBFiles\node2 --replSet foo --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

If I just use mongo shell it would work well like this:

```
mongo --ssl --sslCAFile D:\mongoDBFiles\mongodb.pem --sslPEMKeyFile D:\mongoDBFiles\mongoclient.pem --sslPEMKeyPassword password
```

However it doesn't work with java driver:

```
        final MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("admin", "admin", "password".toCharArray());
        final MongoClientOptions o = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().socketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).build();
        final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), new ServerAddress("localhost", 27018)),
                Arrays.asList(credential), o);

        mongoClient.slaveOk();
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDB");

        final MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("testCollection");

        Document doc = new Document("test Document timestamp ", new Date().toString());

        coll.insertOne(doc);

        FindIterable<Document> itr = coll.find();
        int counter = 1;

        for (Document docu : itr) {
            System.out.println("Document number " + counter);
            System.out.println(docu.toString());
            counter++;
        }
```

Anything went well before adding the ssl options. I also create the keystore just as instructed in the mongoDB website:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file D:\mongoDBFiles\mongodb.crt -keystore mongoKeyStore -storepass password
```

And the VM arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mongoKeyStore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

And finally the error stack trace:

```
16:45:31.760 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017, localhost:27018], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
16:45:31.762 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Adding discovered server localhost:27017 to client view of cluster
16:45:31.795 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Adding discovered server localhost:27018 to client view of cluster
16:45:31.796 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=localhost:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
16:45:31.814 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - No server chosen by PrimaryServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=localhost:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
16:45:31.889 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27018] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:2}
16:45:31.889 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:1}
16:45:31.889 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27018] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:2}
16:45:31.889 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:1}
16:45:31.894 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27018] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27018
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
at     com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:461) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at   com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:204) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:89) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at     com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:83) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:43) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_03]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1868) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1826) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1809) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1735) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:200) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:314) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:173) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:186) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1319) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:998) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1294) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:685) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:111) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:88) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
... 22 common frames omitted
16:45:31.894 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27017] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
at   com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:461) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:204) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:89) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:83) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:43) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_03]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1868) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1826) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1809) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1735) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:200) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar:na]
... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:314) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:173) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:186) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1319) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:998) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1294) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:685) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:111) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:88) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
... 22 common frames omitted  
16:45:31.895 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27018] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=localhost:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty}, caused by {java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty}, caused by {java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty}}]
16:45:31.895 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty}, caused by {java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty}, caused by {java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty}}, {address=localhost:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty}, caused by {java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty}, caused by {java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty}}]
16:45:32.402 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27018] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:3}
16:45:32.402 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:4}
16:45:32.402 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27018] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:3}
16:45:32.403 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:4}
16:45:32.911 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:6}
16:45:32.911 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5527e20bdea3b318ecf76f4e', description='null'}-localhost:27018] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:5}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I just figured out that the keystore created isn't in the correct path, I will try again and give a feedback latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it was the path, thanks anyone who spent time to read this question!

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\mongoDBFiles\mongodbStore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false
```

Answer (score 1):

There was the same problem with me when we were trying to connect mongo db with spark locally on spark.

Few things to check make sure your spark command is correct. 
 i)spark-submit --master local[8] --class  
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= 
--driver-java-options -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=

ii) also check the mongo configuration of the server i used below 
net:
 bindIp: 0.0.0.0,localhost
 port: 27017
 ssl:
  mode: requireSSL
  PEMKeyFile: test-server1.pem
  disabledProtocols: TLS1_0,TLS1_1

Issue for us was that we were using CAFile: /etc/ssl/caToValidateClientCertificates.pem property in mongo file . So the CA certificate of java trust store was not matching with the java one.

Make sure also if CA certs are matching . if not then remove the line of CAFile:  from mongo .

At mongo server end it was giving error like this  SSL: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error

Answer (score -1):

Exception sending message
This is actually comes from network access problem. In mongo cloud
So we can handle this error
Log into mongodb
Go to Security - Network Access - Add up address - add current ip address

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No. Read the stack trace.  Not a network problem.